# Dapp connection with mobile browser

Tags: wallet, nami-wallet, yoroi, decentralized-applications, ccvault

How do I connect my cardano website (dapp) with cardano mobile wallet. currently, I am using yoroi-frontend for desktop browsers.

Comment: You will be more likely to get answers if you follow the guidelines in [ask]

Comment: @gRebel Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Look in the window object for `window.cardano` and then look for the property `yoroi` and then you can interact with the public API.

To enable the wallet use `window.cardano.yoroi.enable()`. This will return an object with the endpoints to interact with the wallet or will fail if the user does not allow to read the wallet.